# Error al visualizar imagen con cv2 - Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cv2

espero me puedan ayudar, estoy trabajando con la libreria cv2, quiero visualizar una imagen en una frame, pero me genera error, si le quito el frame me la visualiza, pero si coloco el frame que creo me genera error, ademas me deja la imagen abierta, no la cierra.

```
def visualizar_imagen(self):
        frame60 = LabelFrame(self.windows_leer_imagen, borderwidth=0)
        frame60.place(x =20, y = 120)
        path = '/oftica/Visuales/' + self.miid_nombre_imagen + '.png'
        image = cv2.imread(path) 
        cv2.imshow(frame60, image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

me genera el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter      \__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 326, in visualizar_imagen
    cv2.imshow(frame60, image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function   imshow'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't convert object of type 'LabelFrame' to 'str' for 'winname'
>  - Can't convert object of type 'LabelFrame' to 'str' for 'winname'
>  - Can't convert object of type 'LabelFrame' to 'str' for 'winname'
```

Agradezco me pueden ayudar a identificar mi error
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya edite la pregunta

Comment: El error está en que a `cv2.imshow()` tienes que pasarle como parámetro un string y la imagen. En tu caso estas intentando pasarle un tipo `LabelFrame` y la imagen, por lo que te salta un error. Es decir, en lugar de `LabelFrame` espera un string.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, entiendo, aun cuando paso el string, cuando salgo, no me cierra la imagen, queda minimizada, me falta alguna instrucción. Muchas gracias por la ayuda